# Internal error 500 on centos 7.5 (vesta). Timeout?

Tags: linux, centos

After more or less 90 seconds of running script via browser (I need to do it via browser - real big report) I get 500 server internal error.

I suspect this is simple timeout issue, I tried in php: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 900); //900 seconds == 5 minutes` but it didn't help - from what I read server can override php in this.

I'm not a server guy. Could sombody tell me how to set apache/vesta to have 15 minutes timeout?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. Error 500 are usually logged to the Apache Error log.

Comment: after 90 second of loading webpage the apache is stopping automaticly becouse it think webpage is broken somehow - it is not, it's just taking so long to calculate. I need to know how to make apache on vesta give page longer timeout just the same way as I give it more memory in php. Is this clear now?

Comment: I found out there is access to apache cont and php.ini inside vesta admin (server -> httpd ->websever -> configure). I dont see any settings in apache, but I changed timeout in php - no effect. I checked etc/httpd/logs/error_log - but errors are not there... no idea what it is then.

Comment: Ok. it turns out there is second log for specyfic domain etc/httpd/logs/domain/* where I found some php sql serrors but I think they are all connected to this `1943233 upstream timed out (110: Conection timed out) while reading response header from upstream client: xxxx, serwer xxxx, request "GET xxxxxx HTTP/1.1", upstream: xxxx, host xxxx`. Like I said I'm not a serwer guy but I suspected timeout right :) PLEASE HELP!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out vesta has not only apache but also NGINX instaled (I don't know why, could somebody explain? Especialy that I saw vesta instal link and it was set to `nginx no`).

open `etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and set

```
proxy_read_timeout 900;
proxy_connect_timeout 900;
proxy_send_timeout 900;
```

then `sudo systemctl restart nginx` to restart

some more info: https://forum.vestacp.com/viewtopic.php?t=11439